# Custom bot not working with mobile client

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a Custom Bot set up via using [these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/custombot).

The Bot is set up and successfully working in a Team when it is `@Mentioned` from a Teams desktop client or the [web interface](https://teams.microsoft.com/).  When the Bot is `@Mentioned` from a Teams mobile client however, it does not respond.

I added logging to my webhook and have found that it does not seem to be triggered when `@Mentions` from a mobile client are sent.

Is there a bug here or are `@Mentions` from mobile devices not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking custom bots from mobile devices is not currently supported. I wish we had a good reason, but we don't; it fell through the cracks. Thanks for bringing it to our attention and reminding us about it.

We don't have an ETA for when it will be supported, but we do intend to support it.

Comment: Same pretense, ( a sideloaded bot ) not able to respond or go to my bot conversation directly on mobile apps ([screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/uA7te)). Is this caused by the same thing? If so, any update on ETA?